# Already exists (HTTP 409) error Big Query/Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

We have recently set up our import from Google Analytics to Google Big Query, but at the same time as there is a successful Update Table, there are two errors: 'Failed: Create Dataset' and 'Failed:Insert Dataset'

The errors message is below:
Already exists (HTTP 409): Already Exists

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? There doesn't seem to be an issue with the data so I'm not sure what is causing it.

Comment: Welcome! Where have you setup this update and where are you feeling these errors?

Comment: Where do you see this error? Can you provide more details about what you have done and about this error you get?

Comment: I see this error in the Google Cloud Platform, under Activity, when I have selected my Project.
I have not done anything about these errors, and we have followed the step outlined here https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092?hl=en to set up our Analytics data to Bigquery.

Comment: Did you notice any loss of data?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known "issue" within BigQuery Analytics export. As far as I know it is a side effect of how the export is currently configured.

The Google Analytics team is working towards fixing this issue, but you should be able to ignore it if the exports are otherwise successful.

Meaning, if you are not experiencing any other issues you shouldn't be concerned about those two error messages.